# React router shines red when clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Inside my react-router-dom Link, I have an icon. Whenever this icon is clicked, it turns red. How can I prevent this?

[Gif showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAiBp.jpg)

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's difficult to help debug code if you can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

That color comes from default css for html `a` elements.
You just need to override the css `color` of the link.

Simple example:

```css
.my-link {
  color: inherit;
}
```